Integral of Poisson Kernel
This doubt comes from Dupaigne's book named stable solutions of elliptic partial differential equations.
The Poisson Kernel is
\begin{equation}
P(x,y)=\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial n_{y}}=\frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^N} \quad\text{for}\;\; x\in B \;y\in\partial B
    \end{equation}
where G is the Green's function and $\frac{\partial}{\partial n_y}$ normal derivative at boundary.
I want to prove the following property
\begin{equation}
\text{for every} \;\; y_0\in\partial B \;\;\text{and every }\; \delta > 0 \;\; \lim_{x\rightarrow y_0}\int_{|y-y_0|>\delta}P(x,y)d\sigma(y)=0  
\end{equation}
that Poisson kernel verifies. I don´t know if it is a usual property or strange property.
Any advice to prove it?
